# Check Browser back button history

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, browser-history

I have one **single page application** and on some buttons / links some angular js function is called and which changed the page content . Now as it is a single page browser will save the history of original page not angular js links which got clicked and change the content . But I want to store that history in recent visited page so that if some one clicked browser back button , the previous content will be loaded .

**E.g. ,**

Suppose I visited `first Google home page them my app and then click on any link which changes the content of page .`

**Google home (1)> my app (2)> click on link and content changed (3).**

original behavior will be when click browser back button -> `back button will load Google home page .`

currently I am on (3) page and back button will send me to (1) page instead of (2)

Expected behavior ->

```
click on browser back button must move me as 
  (3) then (2) then (1) goggle home page
```

Comment: I am also using the single page application using backbone.js. I have used html push state for managing browser history.

Comment: if that view has a deep url then I think it should work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use html push state in your router function.
eg:

```
var enablePushState = true
pushState = !!(enablePushState && window.history && window.history.pushState)
if (pushState) // New Browser supported
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: "/" }); 
else // Old Browser supported
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Bxckbone is giving error (i guess undefined) . I am trying to use this  `window.history.pushState(stateObj, title, URL);` but whatever url i am using in `stateobj`  it is only refeing me to main url that is '/'

Comment: Yes, backbone undefined, I told you i am using backbone. yes you write here to replace with window. See demo here in page source.
http://html5.gingerhost.com/new-york

Comment: I am using angular js.